# Why is $[-1,1]^2 = [0,1]$?

Tags: arithmetic, interval-arithmetic

I have an example of a function $f(x)=x^2+x$, this is specifically for an example explaining the *dependency problem*.

In it we are interested the values over the interval $[-1,1]$, with them being $[-\frac{1}{4},2]$

In the example we apply the interval in context of the function:

$[-1,1]^2+[-1,1]=[0,1]+[-1,1]=[-1,2]$

I want to know why, in the first step, $[-1,1]^2 = [0,1]$?

Apologies if the answer is trivial, this is not my strong point.

Comment: Where will the square of a number in $[-1, 0)$ lie?

Comment: @BadatMathematics $0<n<=1$ ?

Comment: Yes, and what are the squares of $[0, 1]$? Can you see it's just $[0, 1]$?